# Does the samsung "battery life extender" work?

Tags: battery-life

I have bought a Samsung series 9 15inch (NP900X4C), and there is an option called `battery life extender` :

> Sets the maximum battery charge level to 80% to extend the battery
>   lifetime.

Samsung wrote [an article about it](http://www.samsung.com/us/article/tips--tricks-extending-notebook-battery-life), but I could not find much more information. Does anyone has tested this ? How much longer my battery will last with this option ?

Comment: Dunno what the numbers are, but (speaking as an EE) the concept is sound, and I use a similar feature on my Vaio.  My SWAG is that it should roughly double battery life, for a laptop that is usually plugged in.

Answer (score 13):

The short answer is **Yes**, it will extend the battery life.
Can't exactly tell *How much will it extend your battery life*. But according to my findings and some research papers ***it should roughly double the life***.

As your device uses a **Li-Po** (*Lithium Polymer*) battery, the word “polymer” has been used as promotional hype and otherwise it is almost similar to standard **Li-ion**. So everything that applies to Li-ion also applies to Li-Po.

> A study* claims that overcharging by 0.01V reduced the life of an Li-Ion accumulator by more than 50%. The conclusion was that by reducing the charging to 80% of the full capacity you can prolong the life of accumulator very significantly.

Most Li-ions are charged to 4.20 V/cell and every reduction of 0.10 V/cell is said to **double cycle life**.
**For example**, a lithium-ion cell charged to 4.20 V/cell typically delivers 300–500 cycles. If charged to only 4.10 V/cell, the life can be prolonged to 600–1,000 cycles; 4.00 V/cell should deliver 1,200–2,000 and 3.90 V/cell 2,400–4,000 cycles.

It is sure that a **Partial Charge** is always **better** than a **Full charge** for a Li-ion. And a partial recharge will prolong the battery life.

---

See [here](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) a detailed article on ***Relation between Charge level and Longevity of Lithium batteries***.

[A helpful chart about - How to Charge - When to Charge](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_charge_when_to_charge_table)
<sub>* K. Asakuraa, M. Shimomurab, Т. Shodai, "Study of life evaluation methods for Li-ion batteries for backup applications", Journal of Power Source, 2003, PDF: `http://144.206.159.178/ft/641/92454/1607542.pdf`</sub>

Comment: But don't these batteries have their own protection? 80% is too much for me.